# sync contacts gets stuck midway

Tags: contacts, sync, google

I have about 1700 contacts in my google account. When I try to sync on my android it gets to 938 and then stops.

The last sync date shows for about a month ago, and there's always a black sync icon next to it.

I tried removing and re-adding the account to no avail.
I even did a complete factory reset. No luck.

What gives?

Is there some error log somewhere where i might glean something?

Thanks a million

FWIW: There were a few days that showed 939 or 940 contacts, but most of the time it's 938.

**UPDATE**
I managed to find aLogcat for viewing logs. I tried to resync while the log was running. I'm pasting the log here, though I can't seem to find anything relevant.

===LOG START===

```
W/IInputConnectionWrapper(22844): showStatusIcon on inactive InputConnection
I/Timeline(22844): Timeline: Activity_idle id: android.os.BinderProxy@364c5b66 time:1222199
I/Timeline(22844): Timeline: Activity_idle id: android.os.BinderProxy@364c5b66 time:1235668
I/Timeline(22844): Timeline: Activity_idle id: android.os.BinderProxy@364c5b66 time:1267336
D/ViewRootImpl(22844): ViewPostImeInputStage ACTION_DOWN
V/BitmapFactory(22844): DecodeImagePath(decodeResourceStream3) : res/drawable-xxhdpi-v4/ic_media_play.png
D/ViewRootImpl(22844): ViewPostImeInputStage ACTION_DOWN
D/ViewRootImpl(22844): ViewPostImeInputStage ACTION_DOWN
D/ViewRootImpl(22844): ViewPostImeInputStage ACTION_DOWN
D/ViewRootImpl(22844): ViewPostImeInputStage ACTION_DOWN
V/BitmapFactory(22844): DecodeImagePath(decodeResourceStream3) : res/drawable-xxhdpi-v4/ic_menu_share.png
V/BitmapFactory(22844): DecodeImagePath(decodeResourceStream3) : res/drawable-xxhdpi-v4/ic_menu_save.png
V/BitmapFactory(22844): DecodeImagePath(decodeResourceStream3) : res/drawable-xxhdpi-v4/ic_menu_preferences.png
D/AbsListView(22844): Get MotionRecognitionManager
D/ViewRootImpl(22844): ViewPostImeInputStage ACTION_DOWN
I/Timeline(22844): Timeline: Activity_launch_request id:org.jtb.alogcat time:1298449
E/ViewRootImpl(22844): sendUserActionEvent() mView == null
V/BitmapFactory(22844): DecodeImagePath(decodeResourceStream3) : res/drawable-xxhdpi-v4/sym_def_app_icon.png
D/AbsListView(22844): Get MotionRecognitionManager
D/AbsListView(22844): Get MotionRecognitionManager
D/Activity(22844): performCreate Call secproduct feature valuefalse
D/Activity(22844): performCreate Call debug elastic valuetrue
I/Timeline(22844): Timeline: Activity_idle id: android.os.BinderProxy@35c53605 time:1298728
D/ViewRootImpl(22844): ViewPostImeInputStage ACTION_DOWN
D/AbsListView(22844): Get MotionRecognitionManager
W/InputEventReceiver(22844): Attempted to finish an input event but the input event receiver has already been disposed.
E/ViewRootImpl(22844): sendUserActionEvent() mView == null
D/ViewRootImpl(22844): ViewPostImeInputStage ACTION_DOWN
D/AbsListView(22844): Get MotionRecognitionManager
D/ViewRootImpl(22844): ViewPostImeInputStage ACTION_DOWN
W/InputEventReceiver(22844): Attempted to finish an input event but the input event receiver has already been disposed.
E/ViewRootImpl(22844): sendUserActionEvent() mView == null
D/ViewRootImpl(22844): ViewPostImeInputStage ACTION_DOWN
D/ViewRootImpl(22844): ViewPostImeInputStage ACTION_DOWN
I/Timeline(22844): Timeline: Activity_idle id: android.os.BinderProxy@364c5b66 time:1321370
D/ViewRootImpl(22844): ViewPostImeInputStage ACTION_DOWN
D/ViewRootImpl(22844): ViewPostImeInputStage ACTION_DOWN
D/ViewRootImpl(22844): ViewPostImeInputStage ACTION_DOWN
D/ViewRootImpl(22844): ViewPostImeInputStage ACTION_DOWN
D/AbsListView(22844): Get MotionRecognitionManager
V/BitmapFactory(22844): DecodeImagePath(decodeResourceStream3) : res/drawable-xxhdpi-v4/ic_media_previous.png
V/BitmapFactory(22844): DecodeImagePath(decodeResourceStream3) : res/drawable-xxhdpi-v4/ic_media_next.png
D/ViewRootImpl(22844): ViewPostImeInputStage ACTION_DOWN
W/InputEventReceiver(22844): Attempted to finish an input event but the input event receiver has already been disposed.
W/InputEventReceiver(22844): Attempted to finish an input event but the input event receiver has already been disposed.
E/ViewRootImpl(22844): sendUserActionEvent() mView == null
--------- beginning of system
W/ViewRootImpl(22844): Dropping event due to root view being removed: MotionEvent { action=ACTION_MOVE, id[0]=0, x[0]=543.0, y[0]=501.0, toolType[0]=TOOL_TYPE_FINGER, buttonState=0, metaState=0, flags=0x0, edgeFlags=0x0, pointerCount=1, historySize=0, eventTime=1336367, downTime=1336357, deviceId=9, source=0x1002 }
D/ViewRootImpl(22844): ViewPostImeInputStage ACTION_DOWN
D/AbsListView(22844): Get MotionRecognitionManager
D/ViewRootImpl(22844): ViewPostImeInputStage ACTION_DOWN
E/ViewRootImpl(22844): sendUserActionEvent() mView == null
I/Timeline(22844): Timeline: Activity_idle id: android.os.BinderProxy@364c5b66 time:1389772
D/ViewRootImpl(22844): ViewPostImeInputStage ACTION_DOWN
D/AbsListView(22844): Get MotionRecognitionManager
D/ViewRootImpl(22844): ViewPostImeInputStage ACTION_DOWN
W/InputEventReceiver(22844): Attempted to finish an input event but the input event receiver has already been disposed.
E/ViewRootImpl(22844): sendUserActionEvent() mView == null
D/ViewRootImpl(22844): ViewPostImeInputStage ACTION_DOWN
D/AbsListView(22844): Get MotionRecognitionManager
D/ViewRootImpl(22844): ViewPostImeInputStage ACTION_DOWN
W/InputEventReceiver(22844): Attempted to finish an input event but the input event receiver has already been disposed.
E/ViewRootImpl(22844): sendUserActionEvent() mView == null
D/ViewRootImpl(22844): ViewPostImeInputStage ACTION_DOWN
D/AbsListView(22844): Get MotionRecognitionManager
D/ViewRootImpl(22844): ViewPostImeInputStage ACTION_DOWN
I/Timeline(22844): Timeline: Activity_launch_request id:org.jtb.alogcat time:1403435
W/InputEventReceiver(22844): Attempted to finish an input event but the input event receiver has already been disposed.
E/ViewRootImpl(22844): sendUserActionEvent() mView == null
V/BitmapFactory(22844): DecodeImagePath(decodeResourceStream3) : res/drawable-xxhdpi-v4/sym_def_app_icon.png
D/AbsListView(22844): Get MotionRecognitionManager
D/AbsListView(22844): Get MotionRecognitionManager
D/Activity(22844): performCreate Call secproduct feature valuefalse
D/Activity(22844): performCreate Call debug elastic valuetrue
I/Timeline(22844): Timeline: Activity_idle id: android.os.BinderProxy@e740a46 time:1403642
D/ViewRootImpl(22844): ViewPostImeInputStage ACTION_DOWN
I/Timeline(22844): Timeline: Activity_idle id: android.os.BinderProxy@364c5b66 time:1406873
```

===LOG END===

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After short google search I found something that suppose to help: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=ru.ivary.ContactsSyncFix
try using it .
if not, then you could do something like this :
1. Go to Google Contacts and Extract ALL contacts in CSV
2. Delete the contacts (Note that Google contacts has a recovery tool in case one messes up!)
3. Import the contacts in Google Contacts from the CSV file

Comment: Thanks, but I have already downloaded that app, and it didn't help.
also the csv is not a good option, since my contacts are dynamic (they are managed through an external application) and i cannot do this day by day, I need the sync to work. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

in the end the solution was a combination of 2 steps:

1. i deleted all the contacts in the browser as suggested by @br0k3ngl255 , then i reran my sync function, and it was basically ok.
2. actually my sync function also had an issue, that a single contact had more then 1000 email addresses, which had kept the sync from running due to an over quota issue.

now that both these issues were resolved, everything is working ok

Thanks!